# In node.js: How to convert jpg images to binaries data?

Tags: node.js, image, binaryfiles

And on the contrary, how can I convert the binaries data back to image? Because the image data save in the backend are stored as binaries.

Comment: Images are already in binary format. What additional conversion you are expecting?

Answer (score 15):

Try this .

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('image.jpg', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Encode to base64
  var encodedImage = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64');

  // Decode from base64
  var decodedImage = new Buffer(encodedImage, 'base64').toString('binary');
});
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using fs.createReadStream instead of Buffer, Buffer is deprecated method.
Find more info about the differences in https://medium.com/tensult/stream-and-buffer-concepts-in-node-js-87d565e151a0

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution for reading files(obviously you can read images too) and get it converted to binary, I wrote a small code in NodeJS, have a look hope it will help you out. It is all about reading a file into binary, but surely you can convert the string to array or byte-array. If you get suck here, please let me know in the comments below.

Here is a simple yet robust snippet you can try.

```
 params format:
 getBinary({
   path : '<file_relative_path>',
   padlength: '<prepending_padding_length>', (Default: 4)
   debug: false,                             (Default: true)
   limit: 10                                 (Default: Full_File_Length)
   putSpacing: Boolean                       (Default: false)
 })

 Params Description:
   1. path: Specifies the relative file path, to be read.
   2. padlength: After reading the file, it reads object as number 
                 (ex: hex(f): 1111, hex(0): 0), so if you need a 
                 uniform length binary string then you will need to 
                 fill the strings. as hex(0): 0000 when padlength is 4.
   3. limit: limits the read buffer to render.
   4. putSpacing: if true it puts a space after each padlength.


or
getBinary('<file_relative_path>');
```

Get it here: https://computopedia.com/how-to-convert-image-to-binary-nodejs/

Gist: https://gist.github.com/shankha96/cffe620776066078289ea1f8b15956e0